# Remove duplicate rows, and keep newest row based on date column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a huge list of data in excel (250.000+ rows) in the following format:

```
Number  Value1  Date            Value2
40325   1       21/01/11 18.10  2
65485   3       22/01/11 16.47  2
40325   9       25/01/11 19.00  0
70912   8       27/01/11 16.43  2
```

I need to remove duplicate rows based on column 1 (Number), and have no problem doing this using "Data/Remove Duplicates" in Excel, but I need to make sure that I remove the row with the oldest date, and keep the newest, based on column 3 (Date).

In the example above, I would need to remove row 1 and keep row 3, since row 3 is the newest.

I have 4.800 rows with duplicates, so a manual sorting/removing would be a very time consuming job.

Any good suggestions? And tricks to help me out? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick is to sort your table before using `Remove duplicates`. Excel always keeps the first data set of a duplicated row. All consecutive rows are removed.

In your case:

1. Set up a helper column and fill it with numerical values. Start by 1 and use autofill till the end of our table
   [image]
2. Make sure your date column is formatted as date and Excel recognize them as date. Otherwise your sorting wouldn't work
3. Choose `Custom sort` (depends on your Excel version). Sort your whole table by date column from **Newest to Oldest**. That's the important part
   [image]
4. Use `Remove duplicates` and select only your *Number* column which holds your criteria to check for duplicates. Deselect all other columns
   [image]
5. Choose `Custom Sort` again and sort your table by that Helper column we have added at the beginning to get your original row order back
   [image]

Comment: I am just wondering why the `Helper` column is needed?  I have been googling for a solution and came across this answer, as well as [a blog post here](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T013125_Getting_Rid_of_All_Rows_Except_the_One_for_the_Latest_Date.html) (which doesn't include the `Helper` column approach and still seems to work).  Can't you just use an Excel `Custom Sort` on the `Number` and `Date` columns to get the desired result?

Comment: It helps you to track the original row order. its not strictly needed.